# VirtualBox Ubuntu 12 stuck on boot screen with logo

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I am running Ubuntu 12 on Virtualbox(version 4.2.6) on Mac OS X. I installed the Guest Additions by following the instructions from here(http://xmodulo.com/2013/07/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-for-linux.html) and now after I restarted, it gets stuck on the initial screen with the Ubuntu logo and the loading bar which is all lit up.

How can I get around this and perhaps revert the latest changes with the Guest Additions(I assume they are what is causing the problem)?

Comment: latest virtualbox has a feature called 'snapshot' which can keep a history of the guest os. you can revert to any history point if you like.

Comment: sgx1, I'm assuming I don't have that feature since I am using the older version, correct? Do you think If I upgrade to the newer version it would still be available for past changes or only moving forward?

Comment: Which guest additions version did you install? Make sure you always install an additions version matching your Virtual Box version number. To remove guest additions see http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox

Comment: i just checked. version 4.2.6 has snapshot support. but i suggest you to install latest 4.3.x which has more features and bugfixes. snapshots are explicitly created by you. consult the virtualbox help manual for more specifics.

Comment: @sgx1: snapshots need to be taken **before** making changes. We can't revert back if we had not taken a snapshot manually.